# Why is printing the data from response.on("end", callback) different from printing the data from response.on("data", callback)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on learnyounode's HTTP Client assignment.

I was wondering why console logging the data from response.on("end", callback) outputs only the last part of the expected output while console logging the data from response.on("data", callback) outputs the whole response.

Here's my code for the former:

```
var http=require("http");
http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
    var str;
    response.setEncoding('utf-8');
    response.on("error",function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
    response.on("data", function(data){
        str=data;
    });
    response.on("end", function(){
        console.log(str);
    });

}).end();
```

The result shows:

```
                 ACTUAL                                 EXPECTED                
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

   "Veg out"                           !=    "Bodgy"                            
   ""                                  !=    "Chuck a sickie"                   
                                       !=    "Cook"                             
                                       !=    "Dag"                              
                                       !=    "Larrikin"                         
                                       !=    "Hit the turps"                    
                                       !=    "Counter meal"                     
                                       !=    "Hottie"                           
                                       !=    "Veg out"                          
                                       !=    ""                                 

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

The code for the response.on("data", callback) is this:

```
var http=require("http");
http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
    response.setEncoding('utf-8');
    response.on("error",function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
    response.on("data", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });


}).end();
```

The result is:

```
                 ACTUAL                                 EXPECTED                
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

   "Amber fluid"                       ==    "Amber fluid"                      
   "Ankle biter"                       ==    "Ankle biter"                      
   "Bities"                            ==    "Bities"                           
   "Slabs"                             ==    "Slabs"                            
   "Captain Cook"                      ==    "Captain Cook"                     
   "Galah"                             ==    "Galah"                            
   "Battler"                           ==    "Battler"                          
   "Sickie"                            ==    "Sickie"                           
   "Chook"                             ==    "Chook"                            
   "Going off"                         ==    "Going off"                        
   ""                                  ==    ""                                 

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

The former code only logs the last element. Why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good read regarding how the HTTP request works https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

When you do

```
response.on("data", function(data) {
  str = data;
});
```

You replace the value of `str` with the new chunk of data. So on `end`, you do

```
response.on("end", function() {
  console.log(str);
});
```

Where `str` represents the last chunk of data received. You want to concatenate all of the data received like this:

```
response.on("data", function(data) {
  str += data;
});
```